# datatype info over socket; dynamic initialize?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have data coming over a socket that looks like this:

```
(h)(int,char,float,int,char)(/h)(d)(2,a,1.32,45,d)(3,d,3.45,32,a)(/d)
```

The datatype of the data arriving is dynamic and is only known when the header is received. I then have to create corresponding `std::vector`s to store the data. In this case, two `int`, two `char` and one `float` vector. I don't know how to initialize in such a case. Can someone help me out?

Comment: Are there a finite set of types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::vector` can't do this by itself. It sounds like you need something that resembles [Boost.Any](http://www.boost.org/doc/html/any.html) or [Boost.Variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/html/variant.html), you'll need to decide which. If you have a small number of types, a simple `union` might work as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand. If a union contained all the datatypes, I could use one of them at any point of time and it can be initialized with the name of the union. Brilliant. Thanks!